# Azure Storage API ContentDisposition

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I see that Azure has release the ContentDisposition property of a blob: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contentdisposition(v=azure.10).aspx in their version 3.0 of the api.  I've set the property on my existing blobs, but when they are downloaded the content-disposition header is not included in the response.

I've verified that when I FetchAttributes the properties from Azure for that Blob that the ContentDisposition property is in fact populated.

It does work when using SAS, but not when downloading the file without SAS.

If someone has insight please let me know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Can you please check the `DefaultServiceVersion` for your storage account? For `Content-Disposition` to work, I believe the `DefaultServiceVersion` should be **`2013-08-15`**.

To **get** `DefaultServiceVersion`:

```
    var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), false);
    var serviceProperties = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetServiceProperties();
    var serviceVersion = serviceProperties.DefaultServiceVersion;
```

To **set** `DefaultServiceVersion`:

```
    var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), false);
    var serviceProperties = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetServiceProperties();
    serviceProperties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2013-08-15";
    cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
```

Once you set `DefaultServiceVersion`, it should work.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, do you know how to reset the Service version level? The current level on my BLOB account is 'null'. When I see serviceProperties.DefaultServiceVersion. I just want a way to reset it to null again if something goes wrong in future. I tried resetting it to null via code but it doesn't work.