# Is there an approach to force a Azure CDN file to download as a browser attachment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, cdn, azure-cdn

We're building an ASP.NET web application which integrates with a DAM (digital asset management) system. The DAM stores files in Azure blob storage and makes them available publicly using Azure CDN.

We will be making these files (most are PDFs) available to download from our web app. When a user requests one of these files we will provide a custom URL which will run some code on the server (logging the download etc) before returning the relevant file for download.

The client requires that the file is always returned as a browser attachment (i.e. content disposition attachment header). I am curious about what options I have here.

My ideal would be that the CDN URL is abstracted and my custom URL is the public URL for the file. That would allow me to set relevant response headers etc. However, I assume the only solution here would be to download the file from CDN and cache it on my web server which would obfuscate the CDN's purpose. So presumably I have to redirect the client to the CDN public URL once I've done my server processing. But then is there a way I can ensure the file is returned by Azure with the correct response headers to ensure the browser's default download behaviour is delegated?

*** Update ***

In seeing the answers to this question I realised I was perhaps asking the wrong question. Thank you to those of you who answered here. [Follow-up question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752650/what-are-the-implications-of-serving-different-file-types-all-as-application-oct).

Comment: Do these files need to be on CDN? Can they be served/downloaded directly from blob storage?

Comment: Yes, they're static assets ultimately served by a global web platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You need to configure the default version on the blob storage in order for it to show the required header to non-authenticated clients. the question in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472152/keep-getting-old-version-even-after-changing-the-default-service-version-on-azu) has the code to make it work.

Once this is set, and working for anonymous clients the CDN will copy all of the headers across and it should work as expected.

#### Setting ContentDisposition

The functionality is present, you can set ContentDisposition on a [blob property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691966.aspx) However, while this will set the property on the blob, it does not pass through to the header.

I tested this with Powershell using the following (just because its quicker than c#)

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey 

$container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $context 

$blobref = ($script:container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer("images/pier.jpg"))
$blobref.Properties
$blobref.Properties.ContentDisposition = 'attachment; filename="fname.ext"'  
$blobref.SetProperties()  

$blobref = ($script:container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer("images/pier.jpg"))
$blobref.Properties
```

Which produces (amongst others)

> ContentDisposition            : attachment; filename="fname.ext"

However nothing is set when the headers are queried

```
([system.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($blobref.Uri.AbsoluteUri)).getresponse()
```

(to answer comment,. these are the headers returned - while experimenting I also tried with and without a contenttype - hence it being blank here)

```
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
Cookies                 : {}
Headers                 : {x-ms-request-id, x-ms-version, x-ms-lease-status, x-ms-blob-type...}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ContentLength           : 142224
ContentEncoding         : 
ContentType             : 
CharacterSet            : 
Server                  : Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
LastModified            : 01/03/2016 11:29:04
StatusCode              : OK
StatusDescription       : OK
ProtocolVersion         : 1.1
ResponseUri             : https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/cdn/images/pier.jpg
Method                  : GET
IsFromCache             : False
```

And since CDN will only copy the information from the HTTP headers themselves, this data isn't making it into CDN.

### edited (after extended comment chatter!)

For reasons best known to itself Powershell wasn't sending the x-ms-version, so I fell back to telnet which did indeed produce the header -

```
HEAD  /cdn/images/pier.jpg HTTP/1.1
HOST: xxxx.blob.core.windows.net
x-ms-version: 2015-04-05

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 142224
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 11:29:04 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0x8D341C4B1C4F34F"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: b4f41b01-0001-00d7-7cc9-7384c9000000
x-ms-version: 2015-04-05
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 14:49:17 GMT
```

Comment: I don't think Azure Storage has any issues. I believe how you are testing this functionality is not correct. I don't think `HttpWebRequest` will actually initiate the file download. It would simply read the contents of the blob as byte stream and present to the client. When you set the content-disposition header, it is the browser that initiates the download. What happens when you type in your blob URL in the browser (blob needs to be publicly available of course)? Does it get downloaded?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added the headers that are returned with `HttpWebRequest` to the question - I actually tried a couple of other ways too, the data simple isn't presented - obviously we don't care whether it downloads at this point, simply whether the correct headers are present. in this case the `ContentDisposition` header isn't present as would be expected (in [rfc2183](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2183)) When viewed in a browser, the image shows as it normally would. The code is there though, feel free to amend if you feel I have missed something.

Comment: The reason you're not seeing this header is because you have not specified storage service version in your HTTP request. Because you haven't specified the storage service version, storage service picks up the default version (2009-09-19 or something like that). Content-Disposition header was added in a later release of Storage Service REST API. Try something like the following and you will see this header being returned: $req = ([system.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($blobref.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
$req.Headers.Add('x-ms-version', '2015-04-05')
$response = $req.getresponse()

Comment: @GauravMantri How does Chrome et al. specify the storage version in the request? They have no knowledge of what or where it is stored, they just perform a HTTP 1.1 get request. - Running a debug request on the Powershell cmdlet shows `api-version=2015-06-15` [Get Blob Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179394.aspx) requires `2013-08-15` - from what I can see, the `ContentDisposition` is not reflected in the headers. No matter how they are called. Your code also results in the same headers being reported.

Comment: They don't. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894041.aspx: `If a request to the Blob service does not specify the x-ms-version header, and the default version for the service has not been set using Set Blob Service Properties, then the earliest version of the Blob service is used to process the request. However, if the container was made public with a Set Container ACL operation performed using version 2009-09-19 or newer, then the request is processed using version 2009-09-19.`

Comment: A good example to test this would be to create a SAS URL on the blob with latest Storage Service version. Then you should see this header being returned because now you are explicitly telling the storage service to use a particular version.

Comment: Be that as it may, then why didn't I get that header when I did put the correct version in the request, and how does this help the OP since their clients will be using a browser to interface with this. If Azure storage falls back to `api-version=2009-09-19` then my original comment of this being a bug in Storage would be accurate because web clients will not be able to access that HTTP Header because they have no knowledge of api-versions - Have you tried this with an SAS URL? or are you presuming it will work? - Finally Azure Powershell uses `api-version=2015-06-15` so why doesn't that work?

Comment: Please see the code I used: http://pastebin.com/n9s2fY4W. Can you tell me which version you put in your request? `2015-06-15` is not the correct version. The most latest version is `2015-04-15`, and that's what I used. Regarding SAS, I did not use it in this particular example but my whole product is built on SAS and there we use Content-Disposition along with SAS to allow users to download the blob and it works in my product so I know that creating a SAS with correct storage service version works. I would not haste in calling this as a bug in Storage REST API.

Comment: To answer your comment about OP, they could change the default storage service version from default to the latest one and then they need not do anything else because then when the browser requests the blob from Azure Storage, Storage Service would use the latest version even if nothing has been specified by the user.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for the interesting distraction from doing anything useful! it seems that Powershell might be sending an unknown version. (or I'm using it wrong - which often happen!) - either way, I always appreciate the learning of something I'd not been aware of before.

Comment: `For reasons best known to itself Powershell wasn't sending the x-ms-version` - If you trace HTTP traffic for storage calls made by storage client library, then you would see this header with proper value. Now because you're making HttpWebRequest to read the blob instead of using storage client library, you would need to pass this header and that's what I did.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting discussion guys. Very helpful. However, it's led me to ask a new question. See update in OP.