# How to set ContentDisposition using Set-AzureStorageBlobContent

Tags: powershell, azure

Using Powershell (with the Azure module), this works:

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Context $context -File $localfilename -Force -Properties @{ContentType='text/plain'}
```

This does not:

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Context $context -File $localfilename -Force -Properties @{ContentType='text/plain';ContentDisposition='attachment; filename=foo.txt'}
```

The error message I get says,

> Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : Blob properties 'ContentDisposition' with value 'attachment; filename=foo.txt' is invalid

What am I doing wrong?  I can't find any reference as to the accepted syntax for the ContentDisposition property.

Comment: Possible duplicate... See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719641/azure-storage-api-contentdisposition

Comment: @PeterSchneider that is actually not the same scenario.  I read that posting before creating this one.  In his situation, he is successfully using .NET code to set the ContentDisposition and then having trouble with it materializing when downloaded.  In my situation, I cannot get the ContentDisposition set in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. I don't think `ContentDisposition` is supported just yet in Azure Cmdlets (It is fully supported in REST and .Net API though). I am basing my statement on the source code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ServiceManagement/Storage/Commands.Storage/Blob/Cmdlet/SetAzureStorageBlobContent.cs.

Source code from the same page:

```
    //only support the common blob properties for block blob and page blob
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691966.aspx
    private Dictionary<string, Action<StorageBlob.BlobProperties, string>> validICloudBlobProperties =
        new Dictionary<string, Action<StorageBlob.BlobProperties, string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            {"CacheControl", (p, v) => p.CacheControl = v},
            {"ContentEncoding", (p, v) => p.ContentEncoding = v},
            {"ContentLanguage", (p, v) => p.ContentLanguage = v},
            {"ContentMD5", (p, v) => p.ContentMD5 = v},
            {"ContentType", (p, v) => p.ContentType = v},
        };

    /// <summary>
    /// check whether the blob properties is valid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">Blob properties table</param>
    private void ValidateBlobProperties(Hashtable properties)
    {
        if (properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in properties)
        {
            if (!validICloudBlobProperties.ContainsKey(entry.Key.ToString()))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(Resources.InvalidBlobProperties, entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you see the code above, it checks for the properties in the dictionary and `ContentDisposition` is not defined as a key there.

Comment: The repository actually has moved to https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ServiceManagement/Storage/Commands.Storage/Blob/Cmdlet/SetAzureStorageBlobContent.cs. I will file an issue on that one (See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/498)...)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thank you. I have updated my answer with the correct link you mentioned.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thank you both! Thank you for confirming I'm not crazy and for graciously filing a GitHub issue to address the problem!

Comment: The link to the code is dead. It can now be found here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/Storage/Commands.Storage/Blob/Cmdlet/SetAzureStorageBlobContent.cs