# How to update all blob storage files ContentDisposition property?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have a huge number of files stored in azure storage blobs,
Is there a shortcut way to change all files ContentDisposition property?
If not, how can I update this property without downloading and uploading all files back?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20719641/1132334)

Answer (score 3):

I have done it using a loop through all blobs and update them back, not sure if there is an easier way or a shortcut, but for now it did the job.

```
var container = _client.GetContainerReference(_containerName);
var bs = container.ListBlobs(null, true, BlobListingDetails.All).Cast<CloudBlockBlob>();
foreach (var item in bs)
{
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(item.Name);
    blob.Properties.ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(item.Name);
    blob.SetProperties();
}
```

The problem I found so far in this way plus it is a slow process and can take long time, it also put `null` value for all other properties I don't set, so I need to get all properties values first, which I am still try to find out how.