# Content disposition header ignored on download with Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

The content disposition header that I have set on a blob is not included whenever I download that file.

I can see using the storage explorer that the content disposition header is set on the blob. I also have other headers that are successfully returned when I download it e.g. contentMD5.

I followed the advice in this SO answer [Azure Storage API ContentDisposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719641/azure-storage-api-contentdisposition) and updated the DefaultServiceVersion of the storage account to 2017-11-09.

But when I download the file the content disposition is not there.

I am not using shared access signatures.

I have tried this using the Azure storage emulator and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the content disposition header does not work with the Emulator and I did not update the version number on the live storage account when testing the first time.

So in other words, the problem was defining the default version number but this will only work with a live storage account and not the Azure storage emulator.